# svelte toast bootstrap fired only after second event

Tags: bootstrap-4, bind, svelte, toast

Event only fires sometimes, usually after second click of the same type.

So toast wont trigger  more probably if do something like 1x add new, 1x update, 1x remove, etc...

But it will if same action several times like 5x add new, triggers after the second

...

```
// toast notify
import { Toast } from "bootstrap";

let toastEl;
let opc = { text: "", color: "" };

const mostrarMensaje = (text, color) => {
    opc = {
        text: text,
        color: color,
    };
    new Toast(toastEl).show();

};


...
        <!-- Toast notify -->
        <div class="toast-container position-absolute top-0 end-0 p-3">
            <div
                bind:this={toastEl}
                class="toast align-items-center text-dark bg-{opc.color}"
                role="alert"
                aria-live="assertive"
                aria-atomic="true"
            >
```

Sample code url :
https://svelte.dev/repl/04e5e8a7511b44aca203adeb5817f204?version=3.48.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the way you set the background color in your toast:

```js
class="toast align-items-center text-dark bg-{opc.color}"
```

Initially, when the component is first rendered (even though it is not *shown*), `opc.color` is an empty string, making the last class in your definition `bg-`, which is not valid.

If you initially set `opc.color` to `"success"`, you will see the toast appear correctly when you add your first todo. **However** this is not a solution as the issue will persist for your other actions, delete and update.

The solution is to make use of Svelte's `class:` notation to add conditional classes to your toast div:

```js
class="toast align-items-center text-dark"
class:bg-success={opc.color === "success"}
class:bg-danger={opc.color === "danger"}
class:bg-warning={opc.color === "warning"}
```

with this, the correct class will be appended depending on the current value of `opc.color`.

[Working REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c1960c1c1ca14580bf0d164430643d5e?version=3.48.0)

Side note: you will see in the linked REPL that I removed reactive declarations for your add, delete and update functions. These do *not* need to be reactive, and should be declared as normal functions/arrow functions.

Comment: this solved the issue and will accept as answer, but is there any way to make that 3 lines as one? Comething like 
    class:bg-{opc.color}={opc.color !== ""} 
or 
     $: colorClass = opc.color ? `bg-` + opc.color : ''

Comment: ok you gave me the clue, if you want to update your answer i did:
      class="toast align-items-center text-dark {classToast}"

     $: classToast = (valor) =>
  valor ? "bg-"+toast.opc.color : "";

Comment: The solution you settled for is fine, as would be any that avoids appending an invalid `bg-` class. I still prefer the `class:` as it is explicit (clearly expresses intent) and makes uses Svelte's syntactic facilities, but your solution is more flexible (new variants can be added on the fly as long as the corresponding class exists). What really matters is that you were able to identify the root of the problem. Glad I could help.